# Why is no line being printed and estimated coefficients NaN?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The code imports a dataset into the code using `numpy.genfromtxt`, and then tries to plot a regression line through a scatter plot. However the scatter plot prints while the line doesn't. Also the Estimated coefficients output `NaN`. Where does the problem lie?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from numpy import genfromtxt

def estimate_coef(x, y): 
    # number of observations/points 
    n = np.size(x) 

    # mean of x and y vector 
    m_x, m_y = np.mean(x), np.mean(y) 

    # calculating cross-deviation and deviation about x 
    SS_xy = np.sum(y*x) - n*m_y*m_x 
    SS_xx = np.sum(x*x) - n*m_x*m_x 

    # calculating regression coefficients 
    b_1 = SS_xy / SS_xx 
    b_0 = m_y - b_1*m_x 

    return(b_0, b_1) 

def plot_regression_line(x, y, b): 
    # plotting the actual points as scatter plot 
    plt.scatter(x, y, color = "m", 
               marker = "o", s = 30) 

    # predicted response vector 
    y_pred = b[0] + b[1]*x 

    # plotting the regression line 
    plt.plot(x, y_pred, color = "g") 

    # putting labels 
    plt.xlabel('x') 
    plt.ylabel('y') 

    # function to show plot 
    plt.show() 

def main(): 
    # observations 
    x = genfromtxt('/Users/divyanshuvarma/Downloads/graduate-admissions/Admission_Predict.csv', delimiter=',',usecols=(1))
    y = genfromtxt('/Users/divyanshuvarma/Downloads/graduate-admissions/Admission_Predict.csv', delimiter=',',usecols=(8))


    # estimating coefficients 
    b = estimate_coef(x, y) 
    print("Estimated coefficients:\nb_0 = {}  \
          \nb_1 = {}".format(b[0], b[1])) 

    # plotting regression line 
    plot_regression_line(x, y, b) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay with the csv file. Numpy.genfromtxt was also reading the first row of the csv file, which had the names (labels) of the values that followed in the subsequent rows. So I used skip_header=1 to stop it from reading string values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a division `b_1 = SS_xy / SS_xx` in function `estimate_coef`. Did you print out value `SS_xx`, maybe it is zero ? Hope that helps.